# What happens when prob argument in sample sums to less/greater than 1?

Tags: r, sample

We know that `prob` argument in `sample` is used to assign a probability of weights.

For example,

```
table(sample(1:4, 1e6, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1)))/1e6

#  1   2   3   4 
#0.2 0.4 0.3 0.1 


table(sample(1:4, 1e6, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1)))/1e6

#    1     2     3     4 
#0.200 0.400 0.299 0.100
```

In this example, the sum of probability is exactly 1 (0.2 + 0.4 + 0.3 + 0.1), hence it gives the expected ratio but what if the probability does not sum to 1? What output would it give? I thought it would result in an error but it gives some value.

When the probability sums up to more than 1.

```
table(sample(1:4, 1e6, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1)))/1e6

#     1      2      3      4 
#0.1544 0.3839 0.3848 0.0768 

table(sample(1:4, 1e6, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1)))/1e6

#     1      2      3      4 
#0.1544 0.3842 0.3848 0.0767
```

When the probability sums up to less than 1

```
table(sample(1:4, 1e6, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1)))/1e6

#    1     2     3     4 
#0.124 0.125 0.625 0.125 

table(sample(1:4, 1e6, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1)))/1e6

#    1     2     3     4 
#0.125 0.125 0.625 0.125
```

As we can see, running multiple times gives the output which is not equal to `prob` but the results are not random as well. How are the numbers distributed in this case? Where is it documented?

I tried searching on the internet but didn't find any relevant information. I looked through the documentation at `?sample` which has

> The optional prob argument can be used to give a vector of weights for obtaining the elements of the vector being sampled. They need not sum to one, but they should be non-negative and not all zero. If replace is true, Walker's alias method (Ripley, 1987) is used when there are more than 200 reasonably probable values: this gives results incompatible with those from R < 2.2.0.

So it says that the `prob` argument need not sum to 1 but doesn't tell what is expected when it doesn't sum to 1? I am not sure if I am missing any part of the documentation. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: They are normalized to sum to one

Comment: Yes, looking at the output this is what I think as well but couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: perhaps the use of "*probability **weights***" instead of just *probabilities* in the docs. Seem relevant that **vector of weights** is used not probabilities.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Hi_there_Is_there_the_value_of_probability_more_than_1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Good question. The docs are unclear on this, but the question can be answered by reviewing the source code.

If you look at the R code, `sample` always calls another R function, `sample.int` If you pass in a single number `x` to `sample`, it will use `sample.int` to create a vector of integers less than or equal to that number, whereas if `x` is a vector, it uses `sample.int` to generate a sample of integers less than or equal to `length(x)`, then uses that to subset x.

Now, if you examine the function `sample.int`, it looks like this:

```
function (n, size = n, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL, useHash = (!replace && 
    is.null(prob) && size <= n/2 && n > 1e+07)) 
{
    if (useHash) 
        .Internal(sample2(n, size))
    else .Internal(sample(n, size, replace, prob))
}
```

The `.Internal` means any sampling is done by calling compiled code written in C: in this case, it's the function `do_sample`, defined [here in src/main/random.c](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/main/random.c#L461).

If you look at this C code, `do_sample` checks whether it has been passed a `prob` vector. If not, it samples on the assumption of equal weights. If `prob` exists, the function ensures that it is numeric and not NA. If `prob` passes these checks, a pointer to the underlying array of doubles is generated and passed to another function in random.c called `FixUpProbs`, defined [here](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/a28e609e72ed7c47f6ddfbb86c85279a0750f0b7/src/main/random.c#LC432).

This function examines each member of `prob` and throws an error if any elements of `prob` are not positive finite doubles. It then normalises the numbers by dividing each by the sum of all. There is therefore no preference at all for `prob` summing to 1 inherent in the code. That is, even if `prob` sums to 1 in your input, the function will still calculate the sum and divide each number by it.

Therefore, the parameter is poorly named. It should be "weights", as others here have pointed out. To be fair, the docs only say that `prob` should be a vector of weights, not absolute probabilities.

So the behaviour of the `prob` parameter from my reading of the code should be:

1. `prob` can be absent altogether, in which case sampling defaults to equal weights.
2. If any of `prob`'s numbers are less than zero, or are infinite, or NA, the function will throw.
3. An error should be thrown if any of the `prob` values are non-numeric, as they will be interpreted as `NA` in the SEXP passed to the C code.
4. `prob` must have the same length as `x` or the C code throws
5. You can pass a zero probability as one or more elements of `prob` if you have specified `replace=T`, as long as you have at least one non-zero probability.
6. If you specify `replace=F`, the number of samples you request must be less than or equal to the number of non-zero elements in `prob`. Essentially, `FixUpProbs` will throw if you ask it to sample with a zero probability.
7. A valid `prob` vector will be normalised to sum to 1 and used as sampling weights.

As an interesting side effect of this behaviour, this allows you to use odds instead of probabilities if you are choosing between 2 alternatives by setting probs = `c(1, odds)`

Comment: Thank you for a very well researched answer. Regarding your summary at the end specifically point 5). `sample(1:4, 1, prob = c(0, 2, 3, 4))` seem to work as well as `table(replicate(1e6, sample(1:4, 1, prob = c(0, 2, 3, 4))))` with `replace = FALSE`. As mentioned in the docs `They need not sum to one, but they should be non-negative and not all zero`. So it is ok to have probability as 0 for one (or more but not all)  of the value with `replace = FALSE` ?

Comment: Good point @RonakShah. Actually, it will only throw if it is _forced_ to sample with a probability of zero. So you can probably do `sample(1:4, 2, prob = c(0, 0, 2, 3), replace = F)` , but if you specify n=3, then once 3 and 4 are present in the sample, it will try to sample 1 or 2 with a probability of 0 and throw. Can't test this at present...

Comment: @RonakShah I have tested it now and this is indeed the behaviour. Answer updated.

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned, the weights are normalized to sum to 1 as can be demonstrated:

```
> x/sum(x)
[1] 0.15384615 0.38461538 0.38461538 0.07692308
```

This matches your simulated tabulated data:

```
#     1      2      3      4 
#0.1544 0.3839 0.3848 0.0768
```