# How does the probability argument work in the sample() function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to understand how the weighing works (probability argument) in the `sample()` function in R.

```
# seed
set.seed(123)

# some numbers
x = c(1:100)

# some probabilties
p = seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 100)

# sample size
n = 10000

# sample 10000 times from x with probability p
x1 <- sample(x, size = n, replace = TRUE, prob = p)

# plot
hist(x1)
plot(density(x1))
```

Now is this **approximately** what the probability argument does?

```
# adding weights manually
weight = rep(x, n * p)
# now sample from the weighted vector
x2 <- sample(weight, n, replace = TRUE) 

# plot
hist(x2)
plot(density(x2))
```

The plots look very similar so it seems that might be the case.
[image]

**EDIT**

I think I made a mistake when I added the weights manually, i.e. I used `n*p` but I think I should have used `x*p`. Then the results do change a bit:

```
# adding weights manually
weight = rep(x, x * p)
# now sample from the weighted vector
x2 <- sample(weight, n, replace = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: "Now is this approximately what the probability argument does?" -- depends on what you mean by "approximately". If by that you mean if it is functionally equivalent, then the answer is "yes". On the other hand -- if you are asking if the code does something similar under the hood -- the answer is almost certainly "no". Duplicating elements is not a very efficient way to weight choices.

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman - that's what I was looking for, i.e. whether it's conceptually similar. Although I now realize that my weighing attempt(s) is (are) bad.

Comment: Very helpful answer to understand what `sample()` does under the hood: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59921493/4308815

Answer (score 3):

The results you are getting are expected because by defining `p` as a sequence of evenly spaced numbers, the greater the value of `x` the greater its probability of being sampled. This is a weighted sampling procedure, like you say.

See the following two cases.

In the first case the probability of sampling element `2` is 4 times greater, and the results show approximately this.

```r
set.seed(2022)

# sample size
n <- 10000

v <- 1:2
x <- sample(v, n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1, 4)/5)
proportions(table(x))
#> x
#>      1      2 
#> 0.1976 0.8024
barplot(table(x))
```

[image]

In the case below, the probability of sampling a `10` is over 600 times greater than the probability of sampling any other number in the vector `1:100`.

```r
s <- 1:100
p <- rep(1, 100)
p[10] <- 400
p <- p/sum(p)
y <- sample(s, n, replace = TRUE, prob = p)
proportions(table(y))
hist(y)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! That further illustrates what the probability argument does. In my example, I tried to weigh the vector manually and then use the sample() function *without* the probability argument to see whether the results look similar.